# Back-up Windows 8 installation and license

Tags: windows, windows-8, license

I currently have a dual-boot with Linux 14.04 and Windows 8. I am going to remove my Win 8 partition, since I don't really use it.

Still, I would like to keep my Win 8 license/activation key (Win 8 came pre-installed when I bought the laptop) and also I would like to have an installer on a USB drive in case I wanted to reinstall it.

- I have found third party apps to retrieve your license key, is there
  a "microsoft way" of doing this?
- Also, what would be the best option to create a usb installer for Win
  8?
- Is it possible to embed the two things (e.g. have an installer
  coupled with the license)?

Comment: Actually, I deleted Windows 8 from my ultrabook (wtf? Did I order a tablet??). I just installed it again (for sale), with a https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867.aspx generic key. Then, you can restore your key. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have found third party apps to retrieve your license key, is there a "microsoft way" of doing this?

Yes, simply reinstall Windows 8 and it will reactivate. PCs that came with Windows 8 pre-installed have the key embedded in the BIOS and there is no COA sticker used anymore. If you want you can use third-party utilities to identify and note down your key but it's really not required.

> Also, what would be the best option to create a usb installer for Win 8?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

You can also create an image of the the system partition which will allow you to quickly restore both the OS and all installed apps.

Comment: Only issue, the link you provided only works for Win 8.1 (the software you donwload only makes installer for Win 8.1). I would like to keep Win 8 installation (it is bad enough already), but I cannot seem to find a MS page like the one you posted

Comment: @ThreeDiag: True, but I don't think you'll find an official download for 8.0 unless you are an MSDN subscriber. Your only other options would be to either use your OEM's utilities to create recovery discs (or contact them for a set), or image your installed OS.