# Removing Win8 partition and recovery partitions

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

I am planning to remove my Windows partition from my dual boot. After asking  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/909177/back-up-windows-8-installation-and-license) I learned that my Win8 License key is stored in the Bios and all I need is to create a bootable stick if I ever wish to reinstall windows.

Looking at my disk partition (it is a 1TB hdd) I notice that there are several side partition for Windows (msftres, msftdata, boot/efi).

I assume I should not touch the boot one (where grub resides?).

What about the non-linux, non-boot others? My final goal is to get rid of Win8 and retrieve as much disk space as possible, but have a chance at reinstalling it later on if I ever need it (which I deem unlikely, but you never know).[image: Current system partitioning]

In particular, I am wondering about the different recovery partitions, will they be created anew if I ever reinstall windows as part of the installation? What about the mftxx ones?

Comment: recovery partiions will be recreated, of course, they are also not required to recovery windows if you have an installation disk.  the recovery partitions contain WinRE, installation disks contain WinRE, those partiions are only useful if you dn't have installation disks which all Windows 8 users have access to.